# wordpress redirecting to a site am not sure of when viewing a profile

Tags: wordpress

my wordpress site when viewing a profile of authors sometimes it stays sometimes when refreshed it goes to `http://financetimes.co/work-at-home-mom-true-success-story-googletrader/`  redirects to this hacked site.

is there a php code i can add in Function.php so it dont redirect.

```
if "http://financetimes.co" {
dont redirect
}
```

Comment: Whas it the name of the theme you're using?

Answer (score 2):

You first need to establish if the problem is on your computer side or on the server side.

Try with another computer. If the problem remains, the problem is on the server.

You cannot simply add a "patch". If your website is vulnerable you need to fix it.

You can consider disabling plugin by plugin and/or try temporarily another theme in order to find out the origin of the problem.

Comment: i think its the theme side i removed most of the eval base64 codes only 1 remains which is this site its some where not sure whcih php file has this to load that site.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your wordpress theme is corrupt or contains malware. Download the following plugin to check if your theme contains malicious code;

https://wordpress.org/plugins/tac/

Goodluck!

Comment: You are then able to see which file contains the malicious code!

Comment: Shows theme ok no alerts , my site when viewing post or author profile it redirects to that site this is getting annoying please help , i also told my friends online to test they se it to

Comment: What theme are you using?

Comment: its fixed it was zen cauch pro that caused the problem remvoed it

Answer (score 0):

resolved the problem by removing infected  zen cauche pro plugin thanks stack overflow members.